# run cts with multiple devices in parallel with shards option cannot work with Python subprocess.Popen

Tags: subprocess, popen, sharding, cts

Now, I am trying to run cts automatically with Python.

I can use that on single device but can't run on multiple devices.with same python codes.

[this is the function to execute CTS testing and catching the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk47B.png)

**CTS cannot start testing with --shard 2**
**['android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed', 'run', 'cts', '--plan', 'CTS-hardware', '--shards', '2']**

**CTS can start testing without --shard 2**

**['android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed', 'run', 'cts', '--plan', 'CTS-hardware']**

It can also start testing with a terminal derictly.

**android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS-hardware --shards 2**

My question is how can I start shards CTS testing with python to automatically test CTS?

Comment: query =  ['android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed', 'run', 'cts', '--plan', 'CTS-hardware'], subprocess.Popen(query, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

Comment: os.system('cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS') no problem, os.system('cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS') | tee result.txt no problem, os.system('cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS --shards 2') no problem, os.system('cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS --shards 2') | tee result.txt has problem.  J.F. Sebastian

Comment: Did you find a solution for this